# Xcode 4 and kalviewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, open-source, kal

Do you know how to import the [KalViewController opensource library](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) for iPhone in Xcode 4?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link to tell us which library you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the [Xcode 4 docs for creating a workspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/NewProject/NewProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH2-SW5) with multiple projects.

It handles the dependencies for you.

Comment: Thanks! It worked though I did have Xcode crash on me several times for some reason...

Comment: It may be looking for a non-existent dependency.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

The best way right now is to use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) with

```
pod 'Kal'
```

**Old answer**

I think you should create a new group folder under the Classes folder of your projects, drag into it all the .m and .h files of the Kal library, telling to Xcode to copy the files if they are missing.
This way they will be added to the project and automatically to the targets.

From now on you can use all the imports of the .h files from the library in your whole project.

Does this help?

Comment: I see what you're saying. I actually went with Terry's approach as KalViewController library provides you the whole project. If I do the files separately then I would have to add the pictures and it just seems cumbersome. Either way, thanks!